# Is it possible to dynamically add more Y Axes or more X Axes on chart js?

Tags: javascript, angular, charts, chart.js

I've been trying for a few days to dynamically add custom scales to my chart, using chart js. I am using Angular 2 and Typescript.

I tried it in two different ways. The first one triggers an error. The second one works but it's not what i am aiming for. So what am I doing wrong?

*First method*:
I have a modal which has some inputs to set a custom scale and it returns an object that looks like the scale object from the Chart JS documentation:

```
customScale = {
  id: 'y-axis-2',
  type: 'linear',
  position:'right',
  scaleLabel: {
    display: true,
    labelString: 'scale 3'
  },
  ticks: {
    max: 20,
    min: 1
  }
}
```

I have a function who is supposed to add that scale to the scales array attached to my chart.

```
addCustomScale(customScale: any, axis: string) {
  const ci = this.chartComponent.chart;
  let scale = [];
  scale.push(customScale);
  if (axis === 'Axis Y') {
    ci.options.scales.yAxes = Chart.helpers.scaleMerge(Chart.defaults.scale,{yAxes: scale}).yAxes;
  } else {
    ci.options.scales.xAxes = Chart.helpers.scaleMerge(Chart.defaults.scale, {xAxes: scale}).xAxes;
  }
  ci.update();
}
```

When calling this function, i get an error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'options' of undefined
    at core.controller.js:51
```

So far my chart looks like this:

```
<canvas width="600" height="300" id="canvas" #myCanvas baseChart
      [datasets]="lineChartData"
      [labels]="lineChartLabels"
      [options]="mfChartOptions"
      [legend]="lineChartLegend"
      [chartType]="lineChartType"></canvas>
```

I defined everything in typescript:

```
import {BaseChartDirective} from 'ng2-charts';

declare const Chart: any;
@Component({
   selector: 'app-chart',
   templateUrl: './chart.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./chart.component.css']
})
export class ChartComponent {
 @ViewChild(BaseChartDirective) chartComponent: BaseChartDirective;

 public lineChartData: Array<any> = [
  {data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40], yAxisID: 'y-axis-0', label: 'Series A'},
  {data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90], yAxisID: 'y-axis-1', label: 'Series B'},
  {data: [18, 48, 77, 9, 100, 27, 40], yAxisID: 'y-axis-1', label: 'Series C'}
 ];

 public lineChartLabels: Array<any> = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'];
 public lineChartLegend = true;
 public lineChartType = 'line';
 public mfChartOptions = {
  responsive: true,
  pan: {
    enabled: true,
    mode: 'xy'
    },
  zoom: {
    enabled: true,
    drag: true,
    mode: 'xy'
  },
  legend: {
    position: 'bottom',
  },
  scales: {
    yAxes: [{
      id: 'y-axis-0',
      type: 'linear',
      position: 'left',
    }, {
      id: 'y-axis-1',
      type: 'linear',
      position: 'right',
      ticks: {
        max: 100,
        min: 0
      }
    }]
  },
  annotation: {
    events: ['click'],
    annotations: []
  },
  tooltipTemplate: '<%if (label){%><%=label %>: <%}%><%= value + \' %\' %>',
  tooltips: {
    intersect: true,
    bodySpacing: 4
  },
  plugins: {
    filler: {
      propagate: true
    }
  }
};
```

*Second method*. I just added another scale to the scales that i already have in options, like this:

```
public mfChartOptions = {
  responsive: true,
  pan: {
    enabled: true,
    mode: 'xy'
  },
  zoom: {
    enabled: true,
    drag: true,
    mode: 'xy'
  },
  scales: {
    yAxes: [{
      id: 'y-axis-0',
      type: 'linear',
      position: 'left',
    }, {
      id: 'y-axis-1',
      type: 'linear',
      position: 'right',
      ticks: {
        max: 100,
        min: 0
      }
    }, {
      id: 'y-axis-2',
      type: 'linear',
      position: 'right',
      ticks: {
        max: 80,
        min: 40
      }
    }]
  },
  annotation: {
    events: ['click'],
    annotations: []
  },
  tooltipTemplate: '<%if (label){%><%=label %>: <%}%><%= value + \' %\' %>',
  tooltips: {
    intersect: true,
    bodySpacing: 4
  },
  plugins: {
    filler: {
      propagate: true
    }
  }
};
```

And changed my dataset to:

```
public lineChartData: Array<any> = [
  {data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40], yAxisID: 'y-axis-0', label: 'Series A'},
  {data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90], yAxisID: 'y-axis-1', label: 'Series B'},
  {data: [18, 48, 77, 9, 100, 27, 40], yAxisID: 'y-axis-2', label: 'Series C'}
];
```

This one works just fine, but i want to allow the user to create a custom scale, instead of hard coding it.

Answer (score 2):

you can destroy the chart and run new Chart function again.

Here is fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/cbalakus/fhadc9by/

```
function addYAxis() {
    var leng = window.myLine.options.scales.yAxes.length + 1;
    var clr = chartColors[Math.floor(Math.random() * chartColors.length)];
    opts.scales.yAxes.push({
        type: "linear",
        display: true,
        position: "right",
        id: "y-axis-" + leng,
        ticks: {
            fontColor: clr
        }
    });
        lineChartData.datasets.push({
        label: "y-axis-" + leng,
        borderColor: clr,
        backgroundColor: clr,
        fill: false,
        data: getDatas(),
        yAxisID: "y-axis-" + leng,

    });
    window.myLine.destroy();
    var ctx = document.getElementById("cvs").getContext("2d");
    window.myLine = Chart.Line(ctx, {
        data: lineChartData,
        options: opts
    });
}
```

Comment: I think this is not a totally helpful answer since it does not appear to use ng2-charts (which users chart.js), but uses chart.js directly.